# Loop/iterate through a directory of excel files & add to the bottom of the dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, directory

I am currently working on importing and formatting a large number of excel files (all the same format/scheme, but different values) with Python.

I have already read in and formatted one file and everything worked fine so far.
I would now do the same for all the other files and combine everything in one dataframe, i.e. read in the first excel in one dataframe, add the second at the bottom of the dataframe, add the third at the bottom the dataframe, and so on until I have all the excel files in one dataframe.

So far my script looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd
import os

path = os.getcwd()
path = "path of the directory"
wbname = "name of the excel file"
files = os.listdir(path)
files
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path + wbname)

# I only need the second sheet
df = pd.read_excel(path + wbname, sheet_name="sheet2", skiprows = 2, header = None, 
            skipfooter=132)

# here is where all the formatting is happening ...

df
```

So, "files" is a list with all file relevant names. Now I have to try to put one file after the other into a loop (?) so that they all eventually end up in df.

Has anyone ever done something like this or can help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
list_dfs=[]
for file in os.listdir('path_to_all_xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(file, <the rest of your config to parse>)
    list_dfs.append(df)

all_dfs = pd.concat(list_dfs)
```

You read all the dataframes and add them to a list, and then the concat method adds them all together int one big dataframe.